# How to resize a non-square image to square thumbnail (by adding white space)?

Tags: java, image, resize

I'd like to create a square thumbnail of an image using Java. I've already managed to resize images through a couple of ways. However I'd like to create a **real** square image, also from a non-square image.

Example: the source has a size of 200x400 (widht/height)
the target size is 100x100
The algorithm would then need to resize the image to 50x100 and add 25x100 pixels of whitespace each on the left and on the right.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: *"Can anyone help me with this?"* [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I have tried [Patrick Herrera's code](http://blog.futuremedium.com.au/2011/01/28/a-journey-with-resizing-and-cropping-images-in-java/), the [imgscalr framework](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) and the [java-image-scaling framework](http://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/) - they all perfectly did what I described but none of them are able to add white space. 
I'm quite new to Java so I'm mostly relying on frameworks or existing code pieces to learn and get my stuff done.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a 100x100 background; add the scaled image to it. Use Math.max(width, height) to determine the scale factor. Then, plot the scaled image over the background, use calculations (offset x, offset y) to put it in the proper position.

Comment: Thought about that, too. Was hoping there's some framework out there which already covers that...